# Using if statement with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, if-statement

Can somebody help with me with my if statement code on the bottom?

```
try:
    # Import the modules
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env

    # Set up the environment
    env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Neng\Desktop\Fire_Files_For Oct_2010.gdb"
    env.overwriteOutput = True

    # Prompt user for the input table
    inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    # When this is set up as a script tool, set the input to tables only

    # Get the fields from the input
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(inTable)

    # Create a describe object describing the input table
    descTable = arcpy.Describe(inTable)

    # Create variable to store path to results
    gdbName = descTable.path

    # Create table view to use for selections
    # MakeTableView_management (in_table, out_view, {where_clause}, {workspace}, {field_info})
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(inTable,"tableView")

    # Create a cursor to go through the table view row by row
    fireCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("tableView", "*")

    # Use cursor to find each unique incident type and add it to a list
    # Set up a list to hold unique incident types
    incidentList = []

    # Start cursor iteration
    for row in fireCursor:
        incidentType = row[6]
        if incidentType not in incidentList:
            incidentList.append(incidentType)

    # Result is a list object with all the unique values of the inci_type field
    del row
    arcpy.AddWarning("Made the list of incident types.")

    # Use the names in the list object to select records
    for name in incidentList:
        cityQuery = '"inciType" = \'' + name + '\''
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("tableView", "NEW_SELECTION", cityQuery)
        newTable = gdbName + "\\Oleander_Incident_" + "\\Bedford_Incident_"+"\\Fort_Worth_Incident_"+"\\Hurst_Incident_"+"\\Irving_Incident_"+ name.replace(" ","_")


        # CopyRows_management (in_rows, out_table, {config_keyword})
        arcpy.CopyRows_management ("tableView", newTable)

        itemCount =int(arcpy.GetCount_management("tableView").getOutput(0))
        arcpy.AddWarning("A table called " + newTable + " was created with " + str(itemCount) + " rows.")


    arcpy.AddWarning("Finished.")

    if inTable = "Oleander":
        elif "Bedford">= 600
        elif "Worth" >=600
        elif "Hurst" >= 600
     else:
        "Irving">= 600





except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print  (arcpy.GetMessages(2))
except:
    print ("Process did not complete.")
```

Comment: I need help fixing the if inTable ="Oleander" on the bottom. If anyone knows how to fix the problem, it would be helpful.

Comment: What type of parameter is the variable inTable? What are you trying to accomplish with the if statement?  What do you want to do if "Bedford" >= 600?

Comment: I'm trying to write an “if” statement to control user’s selection. Only if user choose cities other than “Oleander” this script will continue.

Comment: If the parameter inTable is of type Table, it will return a path to the table.  Is the table named "Oleander", is there a field "Oleander", or is there a "Oleander" record in the table?

Comment: Is your if statement correct. It looks like they are a condition statements but then don't do anything . Additionally is the formatting correct as the 3 lines under if inTable = "Oleander": are indented and seem to be missing their nested if statement. I could be wrong as I am no python expert, just trying get it clarified.

Comment: Also, are you able to a text description/summary (at the very top) out lining what the code would/should do and the issues you are having.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! I have closed this question for now until you can edit it with an introduction to the problem and context. Once you fix those issues, you can vote to reopen the post. Also, please take the GIS SE tour to get up to speed on the site: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.

Answer (score 2):

Use "==" for equality testing. Not "=" which is for variable assignment.

```
if inTable == "Oleander": #<--- Note the "=="
    do something
```

Note the rest of your `if` statement is syntactically incorrect and makes little sense.

Comment: Thank you this solve the first problem. Now I'm syntax error on my elif "Bedford">= 600
        elif "Worth" >=600
        elif "Hurst" >= 600
     else:
        "Irving">= 600

Comment: What do I need to do next to solve this. Thank you

Comment: What you need to do is to edit your question and explain exactly what you are trying to do. I can't help you with the rest of your if statement as it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JohnJay, for each of the if/elif/else statements you would need to include a) colons at the end of the statement and b) what to do indented on the next line. Also be sure to watch your indentation. Each of the if/elif/else statements need to be lined up and the "do something" needs to be indented.